# How do you update state in functional components in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm running into the issue where I have created a functional component to render a dropdown menu, however I cannot update the initial state in the main App.JS. I'm not really sure how to update the state unless it is in the same component.

Here is a snippet of my App.js where I initialize the items array and call the functional component.

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value:'item1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value:'item2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value:'item3'
  }
  
]

class App extends Component{

    state = {
      item: ''
    }
    
    ...
    
    render(){
      return{
        <ItemList title = "Select Item items= {items} />
```

And here is my functional componenet. Essentially a dropdown menu from a YouTube tutorial I watched (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8JK5bVoVBw).

```js
function ItemList ({title, items, multiSelect}) {
    
    const [open, setOpen] = useState (false);
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState([]);
    const toggle =() =>setOpen(!open);

    ItemList.handleClickOutside = ()=> setOpen(false);

    function handleOnClick(item) {
        if (!selection.some(current => current.id == item.id)){
            if (!multiSelect){
                setSelection([item])
            }
            else if (multiSelect) {
                setSelection([...selection, item])
            }
        }
        else{
            let selectionAfterRemoval = selection;
            selectionAfterRemoval = selectionAfterRemoval.filter(
                current =>current.id == item.id
            )
            setSelection([...selectionAfterRemoval])
        }

    }

    function itemSelected(item){
        if (selection.find(current =>current.id == item.id)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    return (
        <div className="dd-wraper">
            <div tabIndex={0} 
            className="dd-header" 
            role="button" 
            onKeyPress={() => toggle(!open)} 
            onClick={() =>toggle(!open)}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({robot: e.target.value})}
            >



                <div className="dd-header_title">
                    <p className = "dd-header_title--bold">{title}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="dd-header_action">
                    <p>{open ? 'Close' : 'Open'}</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                {open && (
                    <ul className ="dd-list">
                        {item.map(item =>(
                            <li className="dd-list-item" key={item.id}>
                                <button type ="button" 
                                onClick={() => handleOnClick(item)}>
                                    <span>{item.value}</span>
                                    <span>{itemSelected(item) && 'Selected'}</span>
                                </button>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                )}
                </div>
    )
}
const clickOutsideConfig ={
    handleClickOutside: () => RobotList.handleClickOutside
}
```

I tried passing props and mutating the state in the functional component, but nothing gets changed. I suspect that it needs to be changed in the itemSelected function, but I'm not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to update the state of parent component from the child component , then handler pass the changeHandler as prop to the child component .

Answer (score 0):

In a function component, you have the setters of the state variables. In your example, you can directly use `setOpen(...)` or `setSelection(...)`. In case of a boolean state variable, you could just toggle by using `setOpen(!open)`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html (Chapter "Updating State") for further details.

Answer (score -2):

So you need to do something like below . Here we are passing handleChange in parent Component as props to the child component and in Child Component we are calling the method as **props.onChange**

Parent Component:

```
  class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value :''
    }
  }
  
  handleChange = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({ value: newValue });
  }
 
  render() {
    return <Child value={this.state.value} onChange = {this.handleChange} />
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
function Child(props) {
    function handleChange(event) {
        // Here, we invoke the callback with the new value
        props.onChange(event.target.value);
    }
  
    return <input value={props.value} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this if the parent component is a class component? I just need to store the selected value from the functional component. I have a function which checks which item is selected, but I'm not sure how to save that selection

Comment: I update the answer , in case if the parent component is a class component